# How to Determine ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Validation State inside the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to customize the validation message style. The way I am approaching this is to wrap the ValidationSummary helper with a styled div. The problem I have is that the div is visible even when there is no error on the page. Is there a way to determine if the ModelState has an error inside the view? Or should I approach this problem some other way.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work?
`ViewData.ModelState.IsValid`